# Need sudo sometimes when I wakeup from suspend

Tags: suspend, password, ssd, wakeup, auto-login

Have z400 HP with Xeon W3550 with a KINGSTON SA400S3 (0100) SSD and Ubuntu 22:04. It says I need password to wake up the SSD. Have choose automatic log in. I have also ordninary disks i the machine.

I cannot se where I may change somting lake that i Disks.

Is there someone how know what I can do?

/Cheers

/Edit. 20230612 18:13 The problem may be becouse the rest of the HHD, are slow,and teke about 8 second to start. Last line in start up message are:
[32522.805759] ata3: softreset failed (1st FIS failed). On computers with only ssd, it's take only one or two seconds.